# Help with an SQL Query

Tags: sql, oracle

i have this table that have this for example:

```
 NUM1    BOX     Status     DATA      
134813  119874     1    07.03.21
149950  119874     8    10.12.31
```

What I want to do is to select from the table COMERT, where boxID = 119874, and have status 1, but if in the table have more than one row, compare the dates to see if the date from status 1 is more actual than the others. If it doesn't to not return anything. How could I do this?

Comment: What type of column is your date information stored in?

Comment: The date is stored in Data and the type is Date

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
select * from Comert 
where boxID = 119874 and status=1 
and date=(select max(date) from comert where boxID = 119874)
```